# Javascript recursion -- seems like variable scope is messing things up

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to improve my JS by creating a numbers-to-words function in javascript. Ie, it takes 1234 and spits out "one thousand two hundred thirty four". Coming from a Ruby background and wanting to write something recursive that could handle huge numbers, this is what I wrote:

```
var smallNums = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'tweleve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var suffixes = {"trillion": 1000000000000, "billion": 1000000000, "million": 1000000, "thousand": 1000, "hundred": 100};
var tens = {"ninety":90, "eighty":80, "seventy":70, "sixty":60, "fifty":50, "fourty":40, "thirty":30, "twenty":20}

function inWords (num) {
  sections = [];

  for (var word in suffixes) {
    var suffix_val = suffixes[word];
    if (num >= suffix_val) {
      suffix_multiplier = Math.floor(num / suffix_val);
      var toPush = inWords(suffix_multiplier) + " " + word;
      sections.push(toPush);
      num %= suffix_val;
    }
  }

  for (var word in tens) {
    var ten_val = tens[word];
    if (num >= ten_val) {
      sections.push(word);
      num -= ten_val;
    }
  }

  if (num > 0 || sections.length == 0) {
    sections.push(smallNums[num]);
  }
  return sections.join(' ');
}
```

The problem is, instead of outputting "one thousand two hundred thirty four", it's outputting, in this case, "two two hundred thirty four". I've triple checked the logic, and I'm thinking this has to do with a variable scope issue. Basically, it looks like all of the variables (like, say the `sections` array) are the same across levels of recursion.

So it dives into recursion when the first loop hits the line with `toPush`, and then updates the upper-level's variables from inside the lower level.

What makes this clear is if I throw a `console.log(sections)` after the `toPush` assignment. If the variables were just scoped to one "level" of the recursive function, the first log of sections would be empty, cause nothing in that level had filled it with anything, but it is, in fact "[one]".

At any rate **the question** was how to deal with this in recursive programming with Javascript. Can I specify that a variable should not be global or available to recursions within? Or, if not, what's the Javascript-y way of dealing with something like this?

This was a hell of a weird/unexpected bug to find out (I'm new to JS and didn't see this scoping issue coming), and I'd appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sections` is a global variable, thats why it's the same. Write a `var` in front of it.

Comment: Ha. I had no idea that was the case. I'm so unused to the whole var thing - with Ruby, you don't need that at all. Man. I just wasted at least an hour and a half trying to figure out what was going on. Thanks so much. I'll check the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @Sasha: Don't even start with C or Java then. You even have to declare the data for each variable :P ;)

Comment: You're welcome. It's a good practice to use [ES5 strict mode](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/), if you can. That keeps you from doing this mistake. Also, you can validate your code with [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com). That finds all kind of anti-patterns in your code.